# How to add a legend to my bar and line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to add a legend to by bar/line graph that depicts the red line as "Max" and green line as "Min". I would also like to add a legend title that says "Temperature" but its proving to be difficult. I am trying to replicate a legend such as this graph
[image]
Please assist.

Here is my code:

```r
ggplot(Weather_data_R, aes(x=factor (x=Month,       level=c('Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',"May",'Jun','Jul','Aug')))) +
    geom_col(aes(y=`Rainfall (mm)`), fill= "grey", color = "black") +
    geom_point(aes(y=`Max temp-avg`*10), colour = "red") +
    geom_path(aes(y=`Max temp-avg`*10), group=1, colour = "red", size = 0.7) +
    geom_point(aes(y=`Min temp-avg`*10), colour = "green") +
    geom_path(aes(y=`Min temp-avg`*10), group=1, colour = "green") +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "Temperature (ᵒC)")) +
    xlab("Month") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme_classic()
```

Here is my graph:
[image]

I have tried moving the colour into the aes() but I dont know where to do that because my graph doesnt display the legend when I try those things.

Comment: Please make the question reproducible by including the output of `dput(Weather_data_R)`. Check out [MRE] or https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example.

Comment: You need to place `colour = "green"` and `colour = "red"` inside the `aes` of `geom_path()`. A general rule of thumb: Anything inside `aes`  will generate a legend.

Comment: When I move the colour = "" inside the aes, the legend appears. But it is not in the colours that I want it. How do I insert the legend but also keep the colours scheme of my lines?